# ob_start() slows the script

Tags: php, ob-start

I am using `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` for compressing my script.But the script takes too much time for execution. I added `ob_end_flush()` method in the callback function of `register_shutdown_function()` because i can't add `ob_end_flush()` directly in the code.Is this the problem for the delay?
Please give me suggestions to speed up my script.Thank you

Comment: How do you compare the delay? Did you use a profiler (xdebug, xhprof, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions? Well... Don't use `ob_gzhandler`, use front-end abilities to zip output - apache, nginx can do this.